# MySQL Select all rows that have non-distinct values depending on id

Tags: mysql

See the below tables. I want to list out all rows with Name and Number if the Number is not distinct

table1

```
+------+-------+
|ID    |Name   |
+------+-------+
|1     |A      |
+------+-------+
|2     |A      |
+------+-------+
|3     |A      |
+------+-------+
|4     |B      |
+------+-------+
|5     |B      |
+------+-------+
```

table2

```
+------+-------+
|ID    |Number |
+------+-------+
|1     |1234   |
+------+-------+
|2     |123    |
+------+-------+
|3     |1234   |
+------+-------+
|4     |456    |
+------+-------+
|5     |456    |
+------+-------+
```

I have tried with the following query. This will list all the names that have a non-disctinct number, but it will only give me the first row.

```
SELECT table1.Name, table2.Number
FROM table1, table2
WHERE table1.ID = table2.ID
GROUP BY table1.Name having count(distinct table2.Number) > 1;

+------+-------+
|Name  |Number |
+------+-------+
|A     |1234   |
+------+-------+
```

What I want is to list out all off the rows if there are different Number on the same Name.

```
+------+-------+
|Name  |Number |
+------+-------+
|A     |1234   |
+------+-------+
|A     |123    |
+------+-------+
|A     |1234   |
+------+-------+
```

Comment: SELECT * FROM table2 x JOIN (...) y ON y.name = x.name

Comment: @Strawberry `name` is not a field in table2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can accomplish what you want by joining the two tables together and also doing a second join to a subquery which identifies names having a distinct number count which is greater than one.

```
SELECT t1.Name, t2.Number
FROM table2 t2
INNER JOIN table1 t1
    ON t2.ID = t1.ID
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT t1.Name
    FROM table2 t2
    INNER JOIN table1 t1
        ON t2.ID = t1.ID
    GROUP BY t1.Name
    HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT t2.Number) > 1    -- # distinct numbers > 1
) t3
    ON t1.Name = t3.Name                    -- restrict to matching names only
```

**Demo here:**

## SQLFiddle

Answer (score 0):

You can use a subquery to do this:

```
SELECT table1.Name, table2.Number
FROM table1, table2
WHERE table1.ID = table2.ID
AND table1.Name IN(
    SELECT table1.Name
    FROM table1, table2
    WHERE table1.ID = table2.ID
    GROUP BY table1.Name
    HAVING count(distinct table2.Number) > 1
);
```

Otherwise your `GROUP BY` will only show 1 record per table name

Comment: The SQL query just hangs when I run this. To hard for the SQL? If I run the last SELECT query alone I get all the IDs that should be found (4 in my database), so it looks to be correct?

Comment: Yup...forgot the join condition. Edited my answer...update should work now

Comment: I believe the subquery need to look for the name and not for the ID, names have different IDs. I edited your answer to what I tried, but the query is still hanging. Any ideas? As earlier, the subquery is giving me all the names when I run that separately